# Make Entity Framework (using Linq queries) use alias of custom field instead of redoing the subquery

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

Is there a way to force Entity Framwork to use the alias of a subquery instead of doubling it for an OrderBy?

```
var results = Users.Select( u => new 
  { 
    u.idUser, 
    u.Name, 
    nbChilds = u.Children.Count 
  })
  .OrderBy( u => u.nbChilds );
```

This will be converted in SQL to :

```
SELECT [u].[idUser] AS [idUser], [u].[name] AS [Name], (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM [Children] AS [c0]
) AS [nbChilds]
FROM [Users] AS [u]
ORDER BY (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM [Children] AS [c]
)
```

This means that it will run the count of children twice.  In my case, that is a serious hit on performance that I'd like to avoid.  Is there a way to tell Linq to use the alias in the select so the output would be :

```
SELECT [u].[idUser] AS [idUser], [u].[name] AS [Name], (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM [Children] AS [c0]
) AS [nbChilds]
FROM [Users] AS [u]
ORDER BY [nbChilds]
```

Comment: "This means that it will run the count of children twice." Not if you're using a DB provider that's not terrible.  They're able to optimize queries better than that.

Comment: @Servy SQL Server runs it twice from my tests.  Which one wouldn't do that? I could test it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF6 did a good job generating this query.  EF Core repeates the subquery in the ORDER BY, which for SQL Server at least causes a more expensive plan.

SQL Generation remains an active area of improvement in EF Core. Please file an issue against EF Core for this: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues

In EF 6 query like this

```
        var q = from b in db.Blogs
                orderby b.Posts.Count
                select new
                {
                    b.Name,
                    NumPosts = b.Posts.Count
                };

        var l = q.ToList();
```

Is translated like this:

```
SELECT
    [Project2].[Id] AS [Id],
    [Project2].[Name] AS [Name],
    [Project2].[C2] AS [C1]
    FROM ( SELECT
        [Project1].[Id] AS [Id],
        [Project1].[Name] AS [Name],
        [Project1].[C1] AS [C1],
        (SELECT
            COUNT(1) AS [A1]
            FROM [dbo].[Posts] AS [Extent3]
            WHERE [Project1].[Id] = [Extent3].[BlogId]) AS [C2]
        FROM ( SELECT
            [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id],
            [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name],
            (SELECT
                COUNT(1) AS [A1]
                FROM [dbo].[Posts] AS [Extent2]
                WHERE [Extent1].[Id] = [Extent2].[BlogId]) AS [C1]
            FROM [dbo].[Blogs] AS [Extent1]
        )  AS [Project1]
    )  AS [Project2]
    ORDER BY [Project2].[C1] ASC
```

But on EF Core the subquery is repeated in the ORDER BY clause:

Here's a repro

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace EfCoreTest
{

    public class Category
    {
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; } = new HashSet<Product>();
    }
    public class Product
    {
        public int ProductId{ get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public Category Category { get; set; }


    }

    public class Db : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Category> Categorys { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("server=.;database=EfCoreTest;Integrated Security=true");
            base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }



    class Program
    {



        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            using (var db = new Db())
            {

                db.Database.EnsureDeleted();
                db.Database.EnsureCreated();

                for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                {
                    var t = new Category();

                    for (int j = 0; j < 1000; j++)
                    {
                        var product = new Product()
                        {
                            Category = t,
                            Date = DateTime.Now,
                            Name = $"Category {j}{i}"

                        };
                        db.Add(product);
                    }
                    db.Add(t);


                }
                db.SaveChanges();

            }
            using (var db = new Db())
            {
                var q = from c in db.Categorys
                        orderby c.Products.Count
                        select new
                        {
                            c.CategoryId,
                            ProductCount = c.Products.Count
                        };

                var l = q.ToList();

                Console.WriteLine("Hit any key to exit.");
                Console.ReadKey();

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Here's the SQL it generates

```
SELECT [c].[CategoryId], (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM [Products] AS [p0]
    WHERE [c].[CategoryId] = [p0].[CategoryId]
) AS [ProductCount]
FROM [Categorys] AS [c]
ORDER BY (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM [Products] AS [p]
    WHERE [c].[CategoryId] = [p].[CategoryId]
)
```

and the Time and IO stats for that query:

```
(100 rows affected)
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Categorys'. Scan count 1, logical reads 2, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Products'. Scan count 2, logical reads 960, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 31 ms,  elapsed time = 43 ms.
```

Here's the SQL we wish it generated:

```
SELECT [c].[CategoryId], (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM [Products] AS [p0]
    WHERE [c].[CategoryId] = [p0].[CategoryId]
) AS [ProductCount]
FROM [Categorys] AS [c]
ORDER BY (
    [ProductCount]
)
```

And the Time and IO stats:

```
(100 rows affected)
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Categorys'. Scan count 1, logical reads 2, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Products'. Scan count 1, logical reads 480, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 15 ms,  elapsed time = 20 ms.
```

Comment: I'm using EFCore 2.1.1.  I tried putting the orderby before the select like suggested and got the same result: It makes the count twice

Comment: I have C# entities where some property names are a reserved word in DB (I was not aware) and now all my queries got broken, because linq creates alias with the name of this property. What do I do?? I cannot rename hundreds of property occurences!

Comment: If you have a question, post a new question. Not a comment to an unrelated question.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is converted to SQL like this (if it was Linq To SQL):

```
SELECT[t2].[idUser], [t2].[Name], [t2].[value] AS [nbChilds]
FROM  (
   SELECT[t0].[idUser], [t0].[Name], 
      (SELECT COUNT(*)
       FROM [Children] AS [t1]
       WHERE [t1].[idUser] = [t0].[idUser]
      ) AS[value]
      FROM[Customers] AS[t0]
    ) AS[t2]
ORDER BY[t2].[value]
```

However if you traced it that converting as the one you showed then you could do:

```
var results = Users.Select( u => new 
  { 
    u.idUser, 
    u.Name, 
    nbChilds = u.Children.Count 
  })
  .AsEnumerable()
  .OrderBy( u => u.nbChilds );
```

That would be converted to:

```
SELECT [t0].[idUser], [t0].[Name], (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM [Children] AS [t1]
    WHERE [t1].[idUser] = [t0].[idUser]
    ) AS [nbChilds]
FROM [Customers] AS [t0]
```

Comment: I checked the last queries in SSMS and it's really like I said, it's not using the alias. If I use AsEnumerable() won't the query be executed immediately and the order done with all the results in memory?  It would be worst on the performance no?

Comment: @JamesMcGrath, you are right, AsEnumerable would materialize the query. I showed it like that to give you the idea. Instead of AsEnumerable() you could define your query as to that point and later add it when needed and also do ordering there. The SQL I showed was the result of LinqToSQL. I think you are not using Linq To SQL but maybe EF. Note, the type of ordering is not something that would benefit ordering on the backend so I think that is feasible.

Comment: So it's EF's fault and not Linq?  I'll specify it in the question in that case.

Comment: In general Linq2Sql seemed to produce much better SQL than EF ever did. To bad they halted development on it.

Comment: @Magnus, although they have said that, I am not sure that they really stopped on developing it. To me it looks like the SQL it produces is enhanced even after they said they would lean to EF.